# Most efficient way of unpacking cell array with one nested level

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I am using `cellfun` with `UniformOutput` set to 0. This applies the specified function to each cell, returning the output as a cell in a cell array.

Each of these cells are a cell array with 1 row and 6 columns. For example, a cell array with two cells:

```
ans =
{
  [1,1] =
  {
    [1,1] = 1
    [1,2] = 1
    [1,3] = 1
    [1,4] = 9
    [1,5] = hello
    [1,6] = 3
  }
  [2,1] =
  {
    [1,1] = 1
    [1,2] = 1
    [1,3] = 1
    [1,4] = -33
    [1,5] = world
    [1,6] = 3
  }
}
```

I would like to know the most efficient way to convert this into the 2x6 cell array, i.e.:

```
ans = 
  {
    [1,1] = 1
    [1,2] = 1
    [1,3] = 1
    [1,4] = 9
    [1,5] = hello
    [1,6] = 3 
    [2,1] = 1
    [2,2] = 1
    [2,3] = 1
    [2,4] = -33
    [2,5] = world
    [2,6] = 3
  }
```

Comment: How do you get the _values_ in the second array? And why do you sat it's _logical_ when it contains numeric, non-integer values?

Comment: I deleted logical as I want to avoid confusing with the type. I meant the logical way to unpack the array by stacking each cell as rows on top of each other. Thank you for picking up on the incorrect values in the second array, they were wrong due to copy and pasting the wrong thing. The new example is correct now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `cat(1,data{:})` which uses the [comma separated list](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) `data{:}` to unpack the cell and `cat` to concatenate.